# readonly access to SystemConfiguration non-jailbreak devices

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, vpn, system-configuration

i found that some applications in AppStore like hotpot shield can recognize that you selected their profile in VPN setting or not , or its on-demand switch is enable or not.
i found that setting could be read on this address :

> "/var/preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist"

but i want to know is it possible to read this on non-jailbreak device ?
is there any alternative way to do this ? i mean accessing to our vpn profile in setting ?